# Spring boot test not authenticating websocket when using @WithMockUser

Tags: spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test websocket connections using Spring Boot Tests.

They work correctly when I use a permit all security configuration, but as soon as I add `.nullDestMatcher().authenticated()`, to the websocket AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer, test fails with:
"message":"Failed to send client message to application via MessageChannel in session. Sending STOMP ERROR to client.","stack_trace":"org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied.

I would expect that using `@WithMockUser(authorities = AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)` would leave an authenticated context for the socket. What am I doing wrong?

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@WithMockUser(authorities = AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
public class SocketIT {
    ...
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
        this.sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
        this.stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
        this.stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReceiveAMessageFromTheServer() throws Exception {
        StompSession session = stompClient
            .connect(getWsPath(), new StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {})
            .get(1, SECONDS);
    }

    private String getWsPath() {
        return String.format("ws://localhost:%d/websocket/tracker", port);
    }
```

```
@Configuration
public class WebsocketSecurityConfiguration extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages 
            //.nullDestMatcher().authenticated()
            .anyMessage().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    public static final String IP_ADDRESS = "IP_ADDRESS";

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    public WebsocketConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        String[] allowedOrigins = Optional.ofNullable(jHipsterProperties.getCors().getAllowedOrigins()).map(origins -> origins.toArray(new String[0])).orElse(new String[0]);
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket/tracker")
            .setHandshakeHandler(defaultHandshakeHandler())
            .setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
            .withSockJS()
            .setInterceptors(httpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public HandshakeInterceptor httpSessionHandshakeInterceptor() {
        return new HandshakeInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
                if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
                    ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
                    attributes.put(IP_ADDRESS, servletRequest.getRemoteAddress());
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {

            }
        };
    }

    private DefaultHandshakeHandler defaultHandshakeHandler() {
        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler() {
            @Override
            protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
                Principal principal = request.getPrincipal();
                if (principal == null) {
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ANONYMOUS));
                    principal = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("WebsocketConfiguration", "anonymous", authorities);
                }
                return principal;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
    @MessageMapping("/topic/activity")
    @SendTo("/topic/tracker")
    public ActivityDTO sendActivity(@Payload ActivityDTO activityDTO, StompHeaderAccessor stompHeaderAccessor, Principal principal) {
        activityDTO.setUserLogin(principal.getName());
        activityDTO.setSessionId(stompHeaderAccessor.getSessionId());
        activityDTO.setIpAddress(stompHeaderAccessor.getSessionAttributes().get(IP_ADDRESS).toString());
        activityDTO.setTime(Instant.now());
        log.debug("Sending user tracking data {}", activityDTO);
        return activityDTO;
    }
```

Comment: can you please add the relevant part of your Spring Security configuration or your WebSocket endpoints

Comment: Hi @rieckpil , I've edited above to contain more relevant code.

Comment: I think the http requests before socket upgrade do not go through MockMvc so Spring Boot Test cannot inject the principal. I could not find any tests on the web to test authentication as integration tests, I'm starting to feel like an oddball for trying it :)

Comment: @CristianStancalau did you find any solution?

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne, sadly no.